# SHELL to BATCH : grep -Ev command

Tags: shell, batch-file

I need some help. I have this shell script code and it is working properly.

```
 databases=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%demo%';"  | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema)"`
```

How can I convert it in Batch?

Comment: I need some help . I have this code 

    **databases=`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%demo%';"  | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema)"`

    for db in $databases;
     do
       echo $db
     done;**

How can I do it in windows especialy the grep -Ev .

 I tried 

     **FOR /F "demo" %%D in (`mysql -u$dbUser -p$dbPass -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%demo%';" | findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"`)
    do echo %%DD**

it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a base and adapt to your needs.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "dbUser=username"
    set "dbPass=password"

    set "databases="
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
        mysql -u%dbUser% -p%dbPass% -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%demo%%';" 
        ^| findstr /l /v /c:"Database" /c:"information_schema"
    `) do set "databases=!databases! %%a"

    echo %databases%
```

The `for` command will execute the `mysql` command, that will be filtered with `findstr` for lines that do not contain the indicated strings. For each of the output lines, the code in the `do` clause is executed. Each output line is concatenated to the `databases` variable.