# For loop over array in batch file

Tags: arrays, batch-file, for-loop

I need some help. 
This code

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
    mysql -u%dbUser% -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" 
    ^| findstr /l /v /c:"Database" /c:"information_schema"
`) do set a=%%a
```

has a result if **echo %%a**

```
 sample
 sample_test
 test_sample
```

but after the for loop with that code when i add **echo %a%**
the result is only

```
 test_sample
```

how could it be so that i can still get the same output on **echo %%a**

Comment: So, from the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28405749/2861476), that concatenates the databases names in the variable, if i understand you, what you need is to store a line feed between the names. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This do the trick:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^
%empty line%
%empty line%

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
    mysql -u%dbUser% -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" 
    ^| findstr /l /v /c:"Database" /c:"information_schema"
`) do set "a=!a!%%a!LF!"

echo !a!
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
    mysql -u%dbUser% -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" 
    ^| findstr /l /v /c:"Database" /c:"information_schema"
`) do (
 set "a=!a! %%a"
 echo !a!
)
echo %a%
```

Comment: i already did that sir. what i want is when i add another code **echo !a!** outside the for loop . the output is only **test_sample** wherein i want to display **sample
 sample_test
 test_sample** same as !a! within the for loop.

Comment: @xXxrk04 - so you want to append the result to %a%?

Comment: the result of **!a!** is **sample
 sample_test
 test_sample** and the result of **%a%** is only **test_sample** .. i want **%a%** has the same output with **!a!**

Comment: @xXxrk04 - not sure what you mean.The last `echo %a%` should contain all lines....?